# Traveling from the U.S to Copenhagen (Munich layover - is 1.5 hours enough time)?

Tags: international-travel, short-connections, lufthansa, customs-and-immigration, muc

I will be traveling with 2 checked bags from the U.S to CPH, with a 1.5 hour layover in Munich. will I have to go reclaim my checked baggage and check it again (It's all under the same booking number/Lufthansa). Is the layover time enough? Do I only have to go through passport control or also security?

Answer (score 2):

Your bags should be tagged for Copenhagen and not made available to you in Munich. As you will not have time to leave the airport during your layover, head straight to your connecting gate, without passing baggage claim. Your entire layover should be in terminal 2.

Arriving from an airport in a “safe” country you should normally not have to go through another security check, but it can happen. Just in case, make sure you do not carry any prohibited items. You can still take liquids bought in a US airport or on your arriving flight if placed in a special sealed bag (request when buying).

You will go through passport control in Munich, but not customs inspection.

Munich is a large airport, but unless your incoming flight is delayed you should make it.

Comment: Munich is a large airport, but it _also_ prides itself of being extremely efficient for short connections. The minimum connection times even for change of terminal are below one hour.

Comment: The Lufthansa terminal in Munich is not particulary large, at least when compared to really large European airports. Even if you have to take the underground train between the two buildings, it will take you at most 10-12 minutes to lazily stroll between any two gates.

Answer (score 1):

As other people said, you won't have to claim and re-check your baggage.
I would add that I had multiple times short-time layovers in Munich, even just  55 minutes and I never had any problems, even when my flight had a 20-mins delay.

Munich is a very large airport but signs are everywhere so you will know where to go and should be fine!

Answer (score 1):

I made a trip through Munich Airport from USA to Israel. I had 2 hours to walk through from landing to the next gate. It was a bit rough for me because of mobility issues. We had to walk through a controlled part of the airport through a border check before entering a waiting area for the flight from Munich to Israel. If you do not have mobility issues, you should be fine in 90 minutes as you will already have passed basic airport security be inside the airport security in Munich. The customs/passport checkpoint I passed through was only for those who were on that flight to Israel, but it may be similar for EU/Schengen Entry as Denmark is also an EU country.

So I think you will be fine as Lufthansa planned everything via their booking. Call Lufthansa & look at the airport information for Munich connections.

- Munich Airport Connecting info: https://www.munich-airport.com/connecting-flights-260553

Answer (score 0):

You will NOT have to claim and re-check your bags if the entire booking is under the same ticket. When you go to drop off your luggage at the US airport just confirm with the agent that they'll be booked all the way through to your final destination.

As far as checkpoints, you will have to do both security check and passport control, from my experience transiting from WAW to VIE from a US origin flight.

1.5h should be plenty of time to do all this and you should not have any issues!

Comment: I just transferred in Munich a few days ago, arriving from the US.  There was no security check.

Comment: Ah good to know! That's the only international to intra-schengen transfer I'd done so based it off that.

Comment: My transfer was to a non-Schengen flight.  When doing the transfer in the opposite direction about a year ago, I did have to go through security.  It seems to depend on where you're arriving from (not where you're going to) as noted in Arne's answer.  (This year I am returning via Vienna, however, so I won't have additional information about Munich.)